# Determine the number of characters used by double.Parse

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

This is a straightforward question, but I couldn't find any function that solves it. I need a way to determine how many characters were used to parse a double from a string.

I want to take the remainder of the string and use it to determine what measurement unit it is by doing a simple lookup in a table of symbol strings.

---

## Update

I've awarded the answer to Olivier Jacot-Descombes, as he had the fullest Regex, and beat me to the punch with my own answer of how I'd use Regex. The only flaw in this answer I see is not accounting for the comma and dot swapping places with different cultures (which I did take account for in my answer, although it looks kinda messy).

However the actual solution I'll be implementing will not be using Regex. The reason that I've still awarded the answer is because essentially I was asking the wrong question. I think the Regex answer is the best solution for the question that I asked.

The solution I've come up with is to iterate over the available units and compare to the string using `inputStr.EndsWith(unitStr)` and when I get a positive match, I'll immediately know how long the number is by subtracting the length of the unit string from the test string, and then I can use `double.Parse()` with what's left (after a trim).

Comment: You seem to operate under the assumption that double.parse will stop when it runs out of valid characters for a double. I don't believe it works that way. You must determine beforehand where the value ends and pass an appropriate sub-string to double.parse.

Comment: Could you please give an example of what you want to do

Comment: In C# the `Parse` method process the whole input string. In some cases you need to specify parameters _(e.g. trim white space)_. It is not like in `C`, where the functions ignore leading white space and stop on invalid character.

Comment: Okay, well if I use Regex I can also find where the end of the value should be, I'll update my own answer to reflect this.

Comment: And only as note. It is always good to know what format the number is. Therefore specify used culture in Parse method. And when you know, it should be only number with a unit suffix a splitter based only on suffix may be better: e.g. `^(.*?)(\s*)([a-zA-Z]+)$` see: [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html) and [Regex example](https://regex101.com/r/x2mwp5/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have Regex return the matches, so that you don't need two passes.

```
var parseNumUnit = new Regex(
 @"(?<num>(\+|-)?([0-9,]+(\.)?[0-9]*|[0-9,]*(\.)?[0-9]+)((e|E)(\+|-)?[0-9]+)?)\s*(?<unit>[a-zA-Z]*)"
);

Match match = parseNumUnit.Match("+13.234e-3m");
string number = match.Groups["num"].Value; // "+13.234e-3" 
string unit = match.Groups["unit"].Value; // "m"
```

Here

```
(?<name>expression)    captures the expression in a group named "name".
```

My regex for numbers is quite complex and allows number like `"+13.234e-3"`, `"12.34"`, `".25"`, `"10."` or `"23,503.14"`. If your numbers have a simpler format, you can simplify the regex.

Comment: Although I can use the Regex to specifically parse out the number as a named group, I'd still have to convert this to an actual `double` type by either using `double.Parse()` or by pulling out individual components and building the value myself.

Comment: `Double.Parse()` throws an exception anyway, if the string contains a unit. So, you have to separate number and unit before doing the conversion.

Comment: I took account of that from some previous comments, and handled it in my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a RegEx, like this:

```
(?<double>[\d.]+)(?<unit>.*)
```

It will create two Groups when matched, '`double`' and '`unit`' containing the double value and the unit.

Example:

```
1.25632 meter
```

Here the Group `double` will contain '1.25632' and the Group `unit` will contain 'meter'

Comment: The `double` group isn't going to match negative numbers or numbers with thousands separators, and the `unit` group is going to contain ' meter' (with the space).

Comment: And it can't predict the next earth quake!

Comment: ...Hyperbolic, but also true, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to use Regex to interpret the floating point value and then retrieve the length to know where the unit starts.

```
    public static (double Value, string unit) Parse(string value)
    {
        var result = RegexParseDouble.Match(value);
        if(result.Success)
        {
            return (double.Parse(value.Substring(result.Length)), value.Substring(result.Length));
        }
        throw new FormatException("Value cannot be parsed as a floating point number.");
    }

    private static Regex RegexParseDouble
    {
        get => new Regex(
            @"^[-+]?(\d+" +
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator +
            @"\d+)*\d*(" +
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator +
            @")?\d+([eE][-+]?\d+)?");
    }
```

Ideally I'd rather not have to parse the string myself, and then also have .NET parse the string again to provide the value.

Comment: .NET doesn't have the capability to automatically parse numbers from within a string that contains non-number characters. You were going to have to do something like this to separate the number part of the string from the unit part no matter what. That being said, Olivier Jacor-Descombes' answer is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

A simple option that does not involve regular expressions:

```
var input = "42,666 towels";

// Get a char[] of all numbers or separators (',' or '.', depending on language):
var numericChars = input
                    .TakeWhile(c => c == ',' || c == '.' || Char.IsNumber(c))
                    .ToArray();

// Use the chars to init a new string, which can be parsed to a number: 
var nr = Double.Parse(new String(numericChars));

// ...and the remaining part of the original string is the unit:
// (Note that we use Trim() to remove any whitespace between the number and the unit)
var unit = input.Substring(numericChars.Count()).Trim();

// Outputs: Nr is 42,666, unit is towels.
Console.WriteLine($"Nr is {nr}, unit is {unit}.");
```

---

**Update**

As a response to the comment below, heres's an expansion. I'll admit this ruins some of the elegant simplicity above, but at least it's readable, configurable (expandable), and it works:

```
var nrFormat = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;

// Remove or add strings to this list as needed:
var validStrings = 
    new List<string>{ 
                    nrFormat.NaNSymbol, 
                    nrFormat.NegativeSign, 
                    nrFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator, 
                    nrFormat.PercentGroupSeparator, 
                    nrFormat.PercentSymbol, 
                    nrFormat.PerMilleSymbol, 
                    nrFormat.PositiveInfinitySymbol, 
                    nrFormat.PositiveSign
                };

validStrings.AddRange(nrFormat.NativeDigits);
validStrings.Add("^");
validStrings.Add("e");
validStrings.Add("E");
validStrings.Add(" ");


// You can use more complex numbers, like: 
var input = "-42,666e-3 Towels";

// Get all numbers or separators (',' or '.', depending on language):
var numericChars = input.TakeWhile(c => validStrings.Contains("" + c)).ToArray();

// Use the chars to init a new string, which can be parsed to a number: 
var nr = Double.Parse(new String(numericChars));

// ...and the remaining part of the original string is the unit:
// (Note that we use Trim() to remove any whitespace between the number and the unit)
var unit = input.Substring(numericChars.Count()).Trim();

// Outputs is now: "Nr is -0,042666, unit is Towels"
Console.WriteLine($"Nr is {nr}, unit is {unit}.");
```

As you can see, the input can be a lot more complex now; you can even use something like `var input = "∞ Garden Gnomes";`, which will produce the wonderfull output:

> Nr is ∞, unit is Garden Gnomes.

Comment: But unfortunately also does not handle negative values, inputs with exponential, invalid groupings and possibly a few other things I've not thought of yet. Although I do appreciate the simplicity, I want this solution to be as general as possible.

Comment: @TheBeardedQuack You were right, of course. So I updated my answer with an expansion; I may have gone slightly overboard with this, but I think it ought to work (perhaps with some modification depending on requirements).

Comment: Manual character iteration is overkill in a world where Regex exists.

Comment: @Abion47 That's a little bombastic.. I believe it may be a matter of subjective taste. In general, clarity and understanding can be lost entirely with any moderately complex regex. As for efficiency, there are some gotcha's that can render a regex inefficient, and spotting and fixing such a bug is likely to be harder for an average programmer than a similar bug in a non-regex solution. That said, I *did* admit I might have gone a little overboard here...  ;)

Comment: It may be a bombastic claim, but for a startling majority of cases regarding text parsing, Regex is both more concise _and_ more efficient than manual iteration. (Text parsing is what Regex is designed to do, after all, and it does it damn well.) Whichever method is more _readable_ is really the only matter that is one of subjective taste. Sure, there are gotchas that can make a Regex pattern inefficient, but you can say the same thing about the iterative approach. You can't really judge an approach based on cases of people using it badly. (If you could, C/C++ would be a dead language).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-Regex solution that occurred to me. If you can guarantee that your input will always be in the format number-space-unit, then you can simply do the following:

```
public static (double Value, string unit) Parse(string value)
{
    var values = value.Split(" ");

    double number;
    if (!double.TryParse(values[0], out number))
        throw new FormatException("Value cannot be parsed as a floating point number.");

    string unit = values[1];

    return (number, unit);
}
```

If your input string format is something else but consistent, you can do something similar to this to match that format.